# how to decide size of initial heap and maximum heap

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, heap-memory

I want to change initial heap (-xms) and max heap (-xmx) size in eclipse indigo but I don't know the correct size that must allocated for heap. What are the considerations in determining the size that fit with the application that used?

Comment: depends on your application

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to consider.

First of all - you say that you want to "change" initial sizes of heap and max heap. So, the question is simple: why do you need it? For example, some time ago I had to change my IntelliJ IDEA's heap settings to higher values, because it couldn't handle my project. Or do you have some specific reason to change heap size?

Eclipse's heap settings can be located in eclipse.ini file. At least in my Eclipse Juno, eclipse.ini contains:

```
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

So, initial size of heap is 40 MB, but it can resize up to 512 MB. Check your eclipse.ini - are numbers the same?

And, as I asked previously, could you please tell me, why do you want to change heap settings?

EDIT

Nice tutorial at Eclipse's Wiki about how to change [heap size in Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse?).

Comment: In my app, there is calculation of processing time. Some value of process time have a different with other value (ex: first value = 20,123 sec, second value = 20,899 sec). Maybe this happen because processing data that not stable. 

To reach a good performance, I just know I should set heap size with the right setting and set garbage collector to parallel. If I set heap size too high, the system will hang or the app have a poor performance. And if I set heap size too low, it will get "out of memory" error. Back to my question, How to get the right size for initial heap and maximum heap?

Comment: It looks like there is only one option in this case: you have to test heap size with different parameters and try to find out which heap settings are the best for you.

Comment: But how could you know about the best setting for heap size? What a signs that I need to know if that is a good setting for heap size? Could you please tell me about parameters that make a good heap size setting?

Comment: Well, several things indicate that you're having problems with memory. If you're getting "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space", your application is working slowly - you must increase memory size. At least in my JBoss server I have the following settings: -Xms128m -Xmx512m . I order to determine best settings for your heap you can use profilers, like JProfiler or VisualVM.

Answer (score 0):

initial heap size
Larger of 1/64th of the machine's physical memory on the machine or some reasonable minimum. Before J2SE 5.0, the default initial heap size was a reasonable minimum, which varies by platform. You can override this default using the -Xms command-line option.

maximum heap size
Smaller of 1/4th of the physical memory or 1GB. Before J2SE 5.0, the default maximum heap size was 64MB. You can override this default using the -Xmx command-line option.

you can increass  by

> export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx1g"
>   java -jar jconsole.jar &
>   Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1g

or

Setup JAVA_OPTS as a system variable with the following content:

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"

After that in a command prompt run the following commands:

SET JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"